# Parsing a previously saved HTTP response

Tags: http, clojure

I have previously captured HTTP responses on disk (in the WARC format to be specific) and need a way to parse the responses.

I need to be able to access the headers and header values and optionally get the body if headers fit my criteria.

A WARC file contains the full respons including the HTTP/1.1 line, all headers and the body. I can find enough Clojure libraries to do HTTP requests, but I'm unable to only use the response parsing of such libraries. I'm a Clojure beginner, so I might be missing something.

The WARC parser I currently use gives me a stream with the HTTP response if this matters.

Comment: This looks like what you need. https://github.com/iipc/webarchive-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/archive/io/warc/WARCReader.java

Comment: That just reads the WARC format itself. If you use that library to get the payload of a WARC record you'll end up with the HTTP response as described in my question. So, parsing WARC and getting out the individual records is no problem. After getting the individual record I need to make sense of the HTTP response that is in there.

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to what's shown in this (outdated) example? https://sbforge.org/display/JWAT/Reading+a+WARC+file

Comment: I think OP wants a parser for HTTP requests/responses, enabling him to examine header fields and co. If so, there'd be e.g. [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/io/DefaultHttpResponseParser.html) in Java-land (and it doesn't look to hard to use; see [SessionInputBufferImpl.bind()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/io/SessionInputBufferImpl.html) for ways to handle arbitrary input streams).

Comment: @xsc Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I only mentioned WARC to give my question some more context, but didn't anticipate that the comments would be focused on WARC by doing so. I was able to implement HTTP response header parsing using the Apache HTTP library thanks to your comment, but I'm unable to get the body of the response. This problem is also mentioned in https://github.com/kpelykh/docker-java/issues/13#issuecomment-31991490 but I didn't find a solution for it so far.

Comment: @Bram Have you attempted reading the rest of the data (which should be the body) directly from the SessionInpuBufferImpl? I have no idea if there is anything left to read but that's what I'd try next.